# Replace minicart (Top-Right) Product Images with own

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

I want replace Product images of the minicart (Top-Right) with own.
I have written jQuery to call a service and replace the original images with my own corresponding to the ID.

Is there any other way available and I'm hard coding the minicart file How can I override the minicart images without touching the minicart file (used Vadmin/blanco). Theme independent solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing css file:

```
.top-link-cart { background url('../images/cart.png') left center no-repeat; }
```

You image there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your theme, you'll have to find the template file (.phtml) that is called in a loop to display the products in a minicart (eg : `....template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`)

You'll find something like

```
<span class="product-image">...</span>
```

There you can change the `<img>` 's `src` to your webservice's pictures.

Hope this helps ;)